# Author's affiliation at the end of the article with the article class

Tags: formatting, article, amsart, affiliation, authblk

I'm looking for a good way how to put the affiliation on the last page after all the text, using the document class `article`. For instance, in the document class `amsart` this option is realized by default.

The minimal working example for the document class `article` is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{The title}

\author{Author A\thanks{email@Author.A}}
\affil{Addresses of Author A}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And it produces something like that:

[image]

The minimal working example for the document class `amsart` is the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{The title}

\author{Author A}
\address{Addresses of Author A}
\email{email@Author.A}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And it produce something that looks like I want to:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly different way  to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\gdef\@email{\url{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@endstuff}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}\scshape\@address\\\textit{E-mail address:} \@email\end{tabular}}
\AtEndDocument{\@endstuff}
\makeatother
\title{A title}
\author{Author A}
\address{Addresses of Author A}
\email{email@Author.A}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: While I was playing a bit with my answer, I asked myself, why I didn't use `\AtEndDocument`...

Answer (score 5):

If typesetting it manually is ok for you, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \par
  \medskip
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
    \textsc{Addresses of Author A}\\
    \textit{E-mail address}: \texttt{email@Author.A}
  \end{tabular}}

\title{The title}

\author{Author A\thanks{email@Author.A}}
\affil{Addresses of Author A}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it should be more automated, the following allows you to use an arbitrary number of authors. The macro `\print@author` controls what should be printed for a single author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{author}
\renewcommand*\author[1]{%
  \stepcounter{author}%
  \ifnum\c@author=1
    \gdef\@author{#1}%
  \else
    \xdef\@author{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@author\and#1}}%
  \fi
  \csgdef{author@\the\c@author}{#1}}
\newcommand*\email[1]{%
  \csgdef{email@\the\c@author}{#1}}
\newcommand*\address[1]{%
  \csgdef{address@\the\c@author}{#1}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \xdef\author@count{\the\c@author}%
  \c@author=1
  \print@authors}
\newcommand*\print@authors{%
  \ifnum\c@author>\author@count
  \else
    \print@author{\the\c@author}%
    \advance\c@author by 1
    \expandafter\print@authors
  \fi}
\newcommand*\print@author[1]{%
  \par\medskip
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
    \textsc{Addresses of \csuse{author@#1}}\\
    \csuse{address@#1}\\
    \textit{E-mail address}:
    \href{mailto:\csuse{email@#1}}{\csuse{email@#1}}
  \end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\title{The title}

\author{Author A}
\address{example road A\\example village}
\email{email@Author.A}

\author{Author B}
\address{example road B\\example village}
\email{email@Author.B}

\author{Author C}
\address{example road C\\example village}
\email{email@Author.C}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]